# How I can Add a column at a specific position in a table with python-docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I'd like to insert a column after/before another column using python-docx. Is there any way to do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfVP1.png)
I tried  to add a column and moving it with next but it didn't work.
Here is my attempt, It's WRONG, AttributeError: '_Column' object has no attribute '_tr'

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
doc = Document('test.docx')
t = doc.tables[0]
t.add_column(Inches(1.0))
col0 = t.columns[0] 
col1 = t.columns[-1]
col0._tr.addnext(col1._tr)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So, let's say you have three columns. What you try for example, is to add a column in the second position?

Comment: Also, is `addnext` a method that exists? And `_tr` is not an existing attribute, that's why it gives an error.

Comment: yes I wat to  insert a new column in a specific position , ok for example in the second position

Answer (score 0):

> #### Disclaimer
>
> When trying to open the generated file, Word sees it as corrupted. I cannot understand if it is a problem of mine, or if something in the code bothers Word. Anyway, if you let Word recover the file, you will see that the column is added at the index you specified. I hope that someone gives you a better answer, but at least I try to provide you with a possible solution.

Here is an example to explain my implementation: say that you want to add a column next to the first one. The idea is to add a column to the right-most side of the table, then move all the content from the 2nd column on one column to the right. This will give you a new column.

```py
import os

from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

file_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
doc = Document(os.path.join(file_dir, 'table.docx'))
table = doc.tables[0]

# Add a column to the right-most side of the table
table.add_column(width = Inches(1.0))
# Specify where you want the empty column to be.
# NOTE. 0-based i.e. if you want to enter your column between first and second column, you should set 1.
pos = 1
print("Going to add a new column between col {} and {}.".format(pos, pos+1))

# Iterate over columns starting from the last-but-one and counting backward
col_iterator = range(len(table.columns) - 2,    # start: last-but-one index 
                     pos - 1,                   # end: the specified pos (included) 
                     -1                         # step: go backward
                     )
for col_idx in col_iterator:
    col = table.columns[col_idx]
    # Move the cells one column to the right to make room for the new empty column
    for cell_idx, cell in enumerate(col.cells):
        donor_cell = table.columns[col_idx].cells[cell_idx]
        acceptor_cell = table.columns[col_idx + 1].cells[cell_idx]
        
        # Get all the text in the donor_cell
        txt = "\n".join(p.text for p in donor_cell.paragraphs)
        # Clear the acceptor_cell and paste the text from the donor_cell in it
        # Largely copied from _Cell.text (see [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/docx/table.html#_Columns))
        acceptor_cell._tc.clear_content()
        p_new = acceptor_cell._tc.add_p()
        r = p_new.add_r()
        r.text = txt
        # Clear the donor_cell once its content has been copied
        donor_cell._tc.clear_content()
            
# Save the document
doc.save(os.path.join(file_dir, 'add_column.docx'))
```

> #### Comment
>
> My guess is that a cleaner (but even less efficient!) approach would be to create a new table, and add columns one at a time with the new content you want.

I really hope that someone can give you a better answer, but at least you have something to start working with!